# How do I import files for using in the package sangerseqR?

Tags: r, sequence, bioconductor

I tried modifying the code given in the documentation

```
library(sangerseqR)
x <- read.abif(system.file("extdata", "heterozygous.ab1", package = "sangerseqR"))
```

I need to import files from an external drive for which I modified it to

```
x <- read.abif(system.file("extdata", file.choose() , package = "sangerseqR"))
```

But I am getting an error message.

```
Error in readBin(fc, what = "raw", n = 1.2 * file.info(filename)$size) : can only read from     a binary connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, open = "rb") :
file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
```

Any idea how to correct this ? What else do I need to modify in the code for being able to import files ?

Comment: You'd probably have better luck asking on https://support.bioconductor.org (and tagging your question with the package name).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to load a file that didn't come with the package (i.e. your own data file). In that case, you don't want to use `system.file()`. Instead, just try `x <- read.abif(file.choose())` and then choose the file.

`system.file()` is for getting the full paths of files residing inside of packages, such as the example data a package might provide. When you run the code you provided and choose a file outside of a package, it returns an empty string (i.e. `""`). And indeed if I try running `read.abif("")`, I get the error message you describe.

Comment: I managed to import the file using the command you suggested, but I am unable to access its contents  (=different parameters of the ab1 file such as P1AM and P2AM like the ones given here [link]http://www6.appliedbiosystems.com/support/software_community/ABIF_File_Format.pdf  using the $ operator. I guess it doesnt work for this class.